# QGIS 3 missing vector tab mac

Tags: qgis, vector, qgis-3, osx

I installed QGIS 3 as instructed and the Vector processing tab is missing. I did uninstall all previous versions and Python.

Comment: What language is your installation set to? A good number of people encounter similar issues because of language settings.